# Using Firebase Cloud Messaging in Android library project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-library

This is my app folder structure.

```
Application/
  fcm/
    FcmMessagingService.class
    FcmRegistrationService.class
  google-services.json
  Android-Manifest.xml
```

**Android-Manifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".fcm.FcmRegistrationService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".fcm.FcmMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

---

This is my library folder structure.

```
Library(SubModule)/
  fcm/
    LibMessagingService.class
    LibRegistrationService.class
  Android-Manifest.xml
```

**Android-Manifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".fcm.LibRegistrationService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".fcm.LibMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

With the above implementation, I can capture the `INSTANCE_ID_EVENT` and `MESSAGING_EVENT` only from the application's service classes. The Firebase service classes in the library module is not at all triggered.

Is it possible to trigger both the service classes in both Application and Library module when the Firebase messages are received?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Blagojco Yes, I found a work around for this. In my library I added the actual FCM services  and the application's FCM service classes will extend my library's FCM services instead of Google's FCM services.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, I too had to register the library service in Lib manifest as well as App manifest. Trying to figure out which actually is required

```
<service android:name="com.libPackage.FCMService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any problem to implement it on a library module. I just implemented all the services in the library and declare them in the client manifest.

This is how my project looks like:

```
app
  java
    com.example.app
      MainActivity.java
      MyApplication.java
mylibrary
  java
    com.example.library
      MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.java
      MyFirebaseMessagingService.java
```

<sup>[Actual folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD3pc.png)</sup>

The `google-services.json` file is in the client's app directory. Inside the client `build.gradle` file, it has the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.